# Escaping special characters in grep regex

Tags: linux, bash, regex, grep

I am trying to run a grep regular expression on a file, where I have to exclude lines where "00" and "0" appear. I came up with this expression:

`grep -a -E \"stored\"\:\ \"\*123\*(?!00)[0-9]{2,5}\#\" $filename`

But when I try to run it in bash, I either get

`-bash !00: event not found`, or (once I have typed `set +H`),

`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('`

Please what do I need to do to properly escape this regular expression in bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an error message because you did not escape `!`, which has a special meaning in the shell. To use that as part of the pattern parameter of `grep`, you must quote it or escape it.

Instead of quoting every single special character one by one, it's a lot easier to enclose the entire pattern within single or double-quotes (depending on your purpose), for example:

```
grep -a -P '"stored": "*123*(?!00)[0-9]{2,5}#"'
```

Also note that I replaced `-E` with `-P`, because negative lookahead `(?!...)` doesn't work in typical implementations of `grep` extended regex. The `-P` flag enables Perl regular expressions, which should support this.